# For a given integer $n$, how many primes $p_1,p_2 \leq n$ such that $\tau(p_1-1)=\tau(p_2-1)$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

This is a curiosity question.

Let $N$ be positive integer, I just want to know how many (an approximation) pair of primes $(p_1,p_2)$ that are less than $n$ and verify  the following identity:
$$\tau(p_1-1)=\tau(p_2-1) $$
where $\tau(n)$ stands for the number of divisors of $n$. more formally :

> For a large integer $N$, is there an approximation of the following number:
>   $$F(N)=\left| \left\{(p_1,p_2)\in \mathbb P_N^2\big /p_1\neq p_2 \ \text{ and } \tau(p_1-1)=\tau(p_2-1)\right\}\right| $$
>   where $\mathbb P_N $ is the set of primes less than or equal to $N$.

**My attempts**
Let's just evaluate $F$ at primes:
$F(2)=0,F(3)=0,F(5)=0,F(7)=0,F(11)=2, F(13)=2,F(19)=4,...$

Thank you.

Comment: I do not think that there is some useful pattern in the number of divisors of $p-1$ , when $p$ runs over the primes. But maybe the number of primes $p$ below $n$ such that $p-1$ has $1,2,3,4,...$ divisors can be estimated. In this case, we could also estimate the number of solutions.

Comment: Two questions: is $p_1,p_2<n$ or $\leq n$? Your question contradicts the title. Also, how is $F(11)=2$? The only pair is $(7,11)$, (assuming $p_1,p_2\leq 11$) unless I am mistaken, so should it not be $F(11)=1$?

Comment: @9814072356 there's also $(11,7)$

Comment: @barto yes, but are $(7,11)$ and $(11,7)$ counted differently? It is unclear whether they are or aren't. I assumed not. In which case $F(19) = ord({(7,11),(11,7),(13,19),(19,13)})$ so should it not be 4?

Comment: I have corrected the typos

Comment: If  prime numbers $p$ are unpredictable, what can you say about $ p-1 $ besides being even? I think it would be better asked given $p$ (not big) determine a prime $q$ such that your condition is satisfied.

Comment: Just a, possibly, useful observation $F(N+1)=F(N)$ if $N+1$ is not prime.

Comment: and $F(p_{n+1})=F(p_n)+\left | K_{n+1} \right |$, where $K_{n+1}=\left \{ (p_{n+1}, p_i) \space \mid \space i=1..n \wedge \tau (p_{n+1}-1)=\tau (p_i-1) \right \}$